# Dashboard with Charts in Angular does not load until resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, charts

I'm working currently on a hobby-project, where I load some data from my database to a dashboard with some charts.
I am getting the data without any problems, but when I try to load the data in my dashboard it does not show the data until I resize the window.
I don't know if this is a Css problem or it's a TS problem of the dashboard with the charts.
could you help me please?

[Dashboard without resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKV0v.jpg)

[Dashboard after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FgBL.jpg)

HTML Bar Chart:

```html
<c-card  >
  <c-card-header>Motoristas e Ocorrências </c-card-header>

  <div class="row" style="display: block">
    <canvas id="chart"
      style="font-size: 40px; height: 838px"
      baseChart
      [datasets]="barChartData"
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"
      [chartType]="barChartType"
      >
    
    </canvas>
  </div>
</c-card>
```

TS Bar Chart:

```js
export class HorizontalBarChartComponent implements OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas!: ElementRef;

  chart:any;
  labels: any = [];
  data: any = [];
  constructor(
    private serviceDrivers: HorizontalBarService,
  ) {  }
  result: any;
  barChartQuantity: any = []
 
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
   responsive: true,
    indexAxis: 'y',
  };

  public barChartLabels:any;
  barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
 
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

  @Input() itemEvents: any;
  @Input() itemDrivers: any;
  @Input() itemAssets: any;
  public FilterDrivers: any;

  cartEventsDrivers(value: HorizontalBarModel) {
    this.FilterDrivers = this.serviceDrivers.filterDriversEvents('1', value).subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.FilterDrivers = resp;
      });
  }
  test: any;
  ctx: any;
  barChartData: ChartDataset[] = []
  refreshFilterDriversTest(data: any) {

    this.FilterDrivers = this.serviceDrivers.filterDriversEvents('1', data).subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.result = resp;
        this.barChartLabels = this.result.map((resp: any) => resp.driver.name),
        this.barChartQuantity = this.result.map((resp: any) => resp.quantity),
        console.log(this.result)
        console.log(this.barChartLabels)
        console.log(this.barChartQuantity)
        this.barChartData = [
          {
             data: this.barChartQuantity, label: 'Ocorrências', backgroundColor: '#e51b4f' ,
          }
        ]
      });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    console.log(this.itemEvents)
    let data2 = {
      "eventsIds": this.itemEvents,
      "driversIds": this.itemDrivers,
      "assetsIds": this.itemAssets,
    }
    console.log(data2)
    this.refreshFilterDriversTest(data2)

    for (let propName in changes) {
      let change = changes[propName];
      this.itemEvents = change.currentValue;
      this.itemDrivers = change.currentValue;
      this.itemAssets = change.currentValue;

    }


  }

}
```

HTML Filter List:

```html
  <mat-card-header style="background-color: #3c4b64">
    <mat-card-subtitle style="color: white"
      >Descrição do Evento</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>

  <ng-scrollbar class="virtual-scroll" thumbClass="white-scrollbars">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
      scrollViewport
      itemSize="50"
      class="example-viewport">
      <!-- <div > -->
        <!-- <mat-selection-list #list  [multiple]="true" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
          <mat-list-option   [value]="description.description" >
            {{ description.description }}
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list> -->
        <mat-selection-list #descriptions [(ngModel)]="selectedOptionsEvents" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange()" >
          <mat-list-option  *cdkVirtualFor="let description of getAllEvents" [value]="description.id" class="example-item">
            {{description.description}}
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
      <!-- </div> -->
      <!-- <div *cdkVirtualFor="let description of typesOfEvents$ | async" class="example-item">
        <mat-selection-list #list (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange()">
          <mat-list-option   [value]="description.description" >
            {{ description.description }}
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
       </div> -->
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> 
  </ng-scrollbar>
    <!-- [(ngModel)]="selectedRights" [multiple]="true"  -->
  <mat-card-header style="background-color: #3c4b64">
    <mat-card-subtitle style="color: white">Motorista</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <ng-scrollbar class="virtual-scroll" thumbClass="white-scrollbars">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
      scrollViewport
      itemSize="50"
      class="example-viewport"
    >
      <!-- <div > -->
        <mat-selection-list #drivers (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange()" >
          <mat-list-option *cdkVirtualFor="let drive of getAllDrivers" class="example-item" [value]="drive.id">
            {{ drive.name }}
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </ng-scrollbar>
  <mat-card-header style="background-color: #3c4b64">
    <mat-card-subtitle style="color: white"
      >Descrição do Ativo</mat-card-subtitle
    >
  </mat-card-header>
  <ng-scrollbar class="virtual-scroll" thumbClass="white-scrollbars">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
      scrollViewport
      itemSize="50"
      class="example-viewport"
    >
      <div >
        <mat-selection-list  #assets (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange()">
          <mat-list-option *cdkVirtualFor="let description of getAllAssets" class="example-item" [value]="description.id" >
            {{ description.description }}
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
      </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </ng-scrollbar>
```

TS Filter List:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-list',
  templateUrl: './filter-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-list.component.scss']
})

export class FilterListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @ViewChild('descriptions') descriptionSelectionList?: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('drivers') driversSelectionList?: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('assets') assetsSelectionList?: MatSelectionList;

  typesOfAssets$: Observable<Assets[]> | null = null;
  typesOfEvents$: Observable<Events[]> | null = null;
  typesOfDrivers$: Observable<Drivers[]> | null = null;
  result$: Observable<Assets[]> | null = null;
  currentUserId?: String;
  typesOfShoes: Events[] = [];
  constructor(private assetsService: AssetsService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private accountService: AccountService,
    private eventsService: EventsService,
    private driversService: DriversService,
    private sessionService: LocalStorageService,
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder


  ) {

    this.sessionService.getTest()
    this.refreshFilterAssets();
    this.refreshFilterEvents();
    this.refreshFilterDrivers();


  }
  selectedOptionsEvents: string[] = [];

  result: Events[] = [];

  public getAllDrivers: any;
  public getAllEvents: any
  refreshFilterDrivers() {
    this.getAllDrivers = this.driversService.listFilterDrivers('1').subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.getAllDrivers = resp.drivers;

      });
  }

  refreshFilterEvents() {
    this.getAllEvents = this.eventsService.listFilterEvents('1').subscribe(
      resp => {
      this.getAllEvents = resp.events;
      console.log(this.getAllEvents)

      });
  }


  public getAllAssets: any;
  refreshFilterAssets() {
    this.getAllAssets = this.assetsService.listFilterAssets('1').subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.getAllAssets = resp.assets;

      });
  }


  onError(errorMsg: string) {
    this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
      data: errorMsg
    });
  }
  onSelectionChange() {
    
    this.addNewItemEvents();
    this.addNewDrivers();
    this.addNewAsssets();

  }

  addNewItemEvents() {
    this.newItemEventEvent.emit(this.descriptionSelectionList?.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value));
  }
  addNewDrivers() {
    this.newItemEventDrivers.emit(this.driversSelectionList?.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value));
  }
  addNewAsssets() {
    this.newItemEventAssets.emit(this.assetsSelectionList?.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value));
  }

  selectedEvents: any;
  @Output() selectedEvent2 = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Output() newItemEventEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() newItemEventDrivers = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() newItemEventAssets = new EventEmitter<any>();
  selectedEventsArray: Array<any> = [];
  getSelectedEvents() {
    this.selectedEvents = this.descriptionSelectionList?.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value);
    console.log(this.selectedEvents)
   
  }

  getSelectedDrivers() {
    return this.driversSelectionList?.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value);
  }
  getSelectedAssets() {
    return this.assetsSelectionList?.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value);
  }
  eventsArray: Events[] = [];



  ngOnInit() {





  }
}
```

HTML Top Dashboard:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
    <div class="card">
      <small class="text-medium-emphasis text-center text-uppercase fw-semibold"
        >Infrações Jan/23</small
      >
      <div class="fs-5 fw-semibold text-center" style="color: #fb184e">
        {{ qtdEvents.lastMonthQuantity | json }}

        <mat-icon class='text-medium-emphasis md-1'
          aria-hidden="false"
          aria-label="Example home icon"
          fontIcon="warning"
        ></mat-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3 " >
    <div class="card" >
       <small class="text-medium-emphasis text-uppercase fw-semibold text-center"
      >Infrações Fev/23</small
    >
      <div class="fs-5 fw-semibold text-center" style="color: #fb184e">
        {{ qtdEvents.currentMonthQuantity | json }}
        <mat-icon class='text-medium-emphasis md-1'
        aria-hidden="false"
        aria-label="Example home icon"
        fontIcon="warning"
      ></mat-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
    <div class="card">
      <small class="text-medium-emphasis text-uppercase fw-semibold text-center"
      >Comparação</small
    >
      <div class="fs-5 fw-semibold text-center" [ngStyle]="{ color: (qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity < 0) ? 'red' : '#21b913' }" >
        {{ qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity | json }}
        <mat-icon>{{
          qtdEvents.lastMonthMinusCurrentMonthQuantity | topBar
        }}</mat-icon>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
    <div class="card">

      <small class="text-medium-emphasis text-uppercase fw-semibold text-center"
        >FMs Instalados</small
      >
      <div class="fs-5 fw-semibold text-center" style="color: #21b913">
        {{ qtdAssets.mainGarageAssetsQuantity | json }}
        <mat-icon class = 'text-medium-emphasis md-1'
        aria-hidden="false"
        aria-label="Example home icon"
        fontIcon="local_shipping"
      ></mat-icon></div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
    <div class="card">
       <small class="text-medium-emphasis text-uppercase fw-semibold text-center"
      >FMs Reservas</small
    >
      <div class="fs-5 fw-semibold text-center" style="color: #134db9">
        {{ qtdAssets.otherGarageAssetsQuantity | json }}
        <mat-icon class = 'text-medium-emphasis md-1'
        aria-hidden="false"
        aria-label="Example home icon"
        fontIcon="warehouse"
      ></mat-icon></div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
    <div class="card">
      <small class="text-medium-emphasis text-uppercase fw-semibold text-center"
      >Faturamento</small
    >
      <div class="fs-5 fw-semibold text-center" style="color: #b8b50a">
        {{ qtdAssets.totalAssetsQuantity | json }}
        <mat-icon class = 'text-medium-emphasis md-1'
        aria-hidden="false"
        aria-label="Example home icon"
        fontIcon="local_atm"
      ></mat-icon></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS Top Dashboard:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.scss']
})
export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit{
  user: any;
  constructor(private qtdEventsService: TopBarService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private accountService: AccountService,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private sessionService: LocalStorageService,

  ) {


    
    this.listQtdEvents();
    this.listQtdAssets();

  }
  qtdEvents:any= <any>{};
  qtdAssets:any= <any>{};

  listQtdEvents() {
    this.qtdEventsService.list(this.sessionService.getTest())
      .subscribe(qtdEvents => {
        this.qtdEvents = qtdEvents

      })

  }


  listQtdAssets(){
    this.qtdEventsService.listQtdAssets(this.sessionService.getTest())
    .subscribe(qtdAssets => {
      this.qtdAssets = qtdAssets
    })
  }



  onError(errorMsg: string) {
    this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
      data: errorMsg
    });
  }

  
  ngOnInit() {
           try{
           this.user= localStorage.getItem('userId');
           console.log('tentativa 100000 ', this.user.branch.id)
        }catch(error){}    
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `refreshFilterDriversTest()` only on changes, so you won't get the chart data until something changes. Call it from ngOnInit. Also, I suggest considering some changes to your current `ngOnChanges` - maybe check for changes of the parameters that have something to do with chart data, and call `refreshFilterDriversTest()` only if that condition returns true. Depending on your use-case and the amount of data you get from subscription, it might be better not to hit he endpoint on each change (like for each resize, button click on page etc.)